# AVFoundation processing live video crashing

Tags: ios, image-processing, avfoundation

I've tried a million different approaches, but can't seem to get my app to stop crashing. I'm trying to crop a section from the live video and display it zoomed in. Problem is, after processing about 400 frames it crashes without fail. Any ideas? The method I'm using is:

```
- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{

}
```

Comment: sounds like you're running out of memory. you can't hold many frames in memory at once, make sure you're not storing them in an array or anything like that.

Comment: What's the crash you're getting from the console?

Comment: Not storing them, and I'm watching memory, it never grows. The crash is the typical unhelpful EXC_BAD_ACCESS with no useful information.